# Could not read the Interrupt Priority after vTaskStartScheduler()

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, freertos, rtos

I want to use `NVIC_GetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn)` function with FreeRtos. I can use this function before the  `vTaskStartScheduler();` but, when I call `NVIC_GetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn)` function after  `vTaskStartScheduler();`, it does not work do you have any suggestion?

```
#include <FreeRTOS.h>
#include <queue.h>
#include <task.h>
/* -- */
static void vTest_NVIC( void *pvParameters )
{
 tprintf("\r\nTask Started..."); 
  /* -- */
  while(1) {
    /* -- */   
    taskENTER_CRITICAL();  
    tprintf("\r\npriority= %d",NVIC_GetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn));   
    taskEXIT_CRITICAL();
    vTaskDelay(3000);;      
  }
}
int main()
{
  portBASE_TYPE xReturn;        
  /* -- */
  xReturn = xTaskCreate ( vTest_NVIC, ( const signed portCHAR * const )"Test_NVIC", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE<<4, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL );
  if( xReturn != pdPASS ) {
    tprintf("\n\rTest_NVIC initilisation problem.\n\r");
  }

  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  NVIC_SetPriorityGrouping(3);
  /* DMA1 Channel4 interrupt setting */
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA1_Channel4_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 11;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);   

  tprintf("\r\npriority= %d",NVIC_GetPriority(DMA1_Channel4_IRQn));   
  /* Now all the tasks have been started - start the scheduler. */
  vTaskStartScheduler();
```

The output of the program is like that.

```
priority= 11

Task Started...
```

Do you have any suggestions to read interrupt priority aftevTaskStartScheduler() start? Thanks from now.

Comment: Is your task running at all? If so, just step into it and see where exactly it hangs.

Answer (score -2):

I don’t know what microcontroller you’re using, but sometimes `printf` use interrupts to send characters through the UART and the like, if you make it a critical section that means the interrupt will never fire. Comment out the critical section lines to see if that’s the case.

Another possibility is that you have the MPU (memory protection unit) enabled, and it is not allowing access to the NVIC registers from a user task. AFAIK FreeRTOS has support for the MPU in Cortex-M microcontrollers, check if that is enabled in your case.